# Is there any difference between width and max-width when used with min-width?

Tags: css

If you specify `width` then your `<div>` will *normally* be that width, but if a large element is next to it, it can be crushed smaller than that width.

You can use `min-width` to prevent your element from being crushed, but if you don't *also* specify `width` then it can grow unbounded (to fill the full width of the container).

You could also use `max-width` in place of `width` to indicate that your element should not be wider than that.

So my question is, is there any difference between `width`+`min-width` vs `min-width`+`max-width` to get an exact width?

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.width {
  width: 80px;
}

.min-width {
  min-width: 80px;
}

.width-min-width {
  width: 80px;
  min-width: 80px;
}

.min-max-width {
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.crusher {
  background-color: red;
  width: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="width">
  width
</div>

<hr>

<div class="min-width">
  min-width
</div>

<hr>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="width">
    hello world this is a bunch of text
  </div>
  <div class="crusher">
    vroom vroom
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="width-min-width">
    hello world this is a bunch of text
  </div>
  <div class="crusher">
    vroom vroom
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="min-max-width">
    hello world this is a bunch of text
  </div>
  <div class="crusher">
    vroom vroom
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the *crush* behavior your are facing is related to the shrink effect of flexbox that you can disable it using flex-shrink:0 (min-width is another way to limit that shrink effect)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I thought it might have been specific to flexbox. I think something similar happens with tables too though -- but I don't know precisely what it's doing.

Comment: with table too there is some complex algorithm related to min-width/width. I think it's more complex than the flexbox one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a difference. I can think about many examples but here is a basic one related to resizable content

```css
.box {
  height:50px;
  border:2px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  resize:horizontal;
  min-width:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="width:80px;">

</div>

<div class="box" style="max-width:80px;">

</div>
```

You can resize the first div but not the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a difference!

It's hard to repo here though, so consider this half-an-answer.

On my site, when you use `min-width`+`max-width` the browser does weird things:

[image]

Notice the "Driver" column is quite a bit wider that the content even though it should have cut off exactly where that ellipsis is.

The "Actions" column OTOH was set to `min-width: 1px; max-width: 1px;` which it's kind of trying to respect by being as tiny as possible, but still comes out to 31.18px.

Now if I use `width`+`min-width` it comes out like this:

[image]

Which looks much better. The "Driver" column is the correct size, and even though the "Actions" column was set to 1px it won't crush the text.

(N.B. no PII was leaked -- this is dummy data; don't try phoning Mabel)

Answer (score -1):

The min-width CSS property sets the minimum width of an element. It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming smaller than the value specified for min-width.

max-width means less than or equal to the width specified in that media query.

Comment: Not what I asked.